# what wrong phpmyadmin - count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable, Line number : 40

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to count user in database to login, what wrong whith my code

```
public function index(){
    //validasi
    $valid = $this->form_validation;

    $valid->set_rules('username', ' Username', 'required',
                array('required'    => 'Username harus diisi'));
    $valid->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]',
                array('required'    => 'password harus diisi',
                      'min_length'  => 'Password minimal 6 karakter'));


    if($valid->run()===FALSE){
        //end validasi
        $data = array('title' => 'Login Admin Tempat Ngaji');
        $this->load->view('back-end/login_view', $data, FALSE);
    //cek username dan password
    }else{
        $i              = $this->input;
        $username       = $i->post('username');
        $password       = $i->post('password');
        //cek di database
        $check_login    = $this->admin_model->login($username, $password);

        //jika ada di db
        //jika ada data 1
        if(count($check_login) == 1) { `//row 40`
            $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
            $this->session->set_userdata('akses_level', $check_login->akses_level);
            $this->session->set_userdata('id_admin', $check_login->id_admin);
            $this->session->set_userdata('nama', $check_login->nama);
            $this->session->set_userdata('status', $check_login->status);
            redirect(base_url('admin/dashboard'), 'refresh');
        }else{
            //jika tidak cocok error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Username atau password tidak cocok');
            redirect(base_url('admin/login'), 'refresh');

        }
```

function login

```
function login
    public function login($username, $password){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('admin');
        $this->db->where(array('username'   => $username,
                                'password'  => sha1($password)));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row();
    }
```

Looking for I saw that some have this error in their code, but I did not find anyone who received it in phpMyAdmin ...

What should I d

Comment: What is $check_login? Var_dump it

Comment: Can you post code inside `admin_model->login()`

Comment: sure

public function login($username, $password){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('admin');
  $this->db->where(array('username'  => $username,
        'password'  => sha1($password)));
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->row();
 }

Comment: Unclear what you are asking - is this your own code that you have written yourself, or is this phpMyAdmin code? If the former, then what is the connection to phpMyAdmin here?

Comment: Your $check_login is null that's why you got this error. Just check isset($check_login) before checking count.

Comment: thanks.. i can fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

MODEL:

```
public function login($username, $password){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('admin');
        $this->db->where(array('username'   => $username,
                                'password'  => sha1($password)));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() !== 1) {
            return false;
        }
        return $query->row();
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    if($check_login) { `//row 40`
        $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
        $this->session->set_userdata('akses_level', $check_login->akses_level);
        $this->session->set_userdata('id_admin', $check_login->id_admin);
        $this->session->set_userdata('nama', $check_login->nama);
        $this->session->set_userdata('status', $check_login->status);
        redirect(base_url('admin/dashboard'), 'refresh');
    }else{
        //jika tidak cocok error
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Username atau password tidak cocok');
        redirect(base_url('admin/login'), 'refresh');

    }
```

also `sha1` like `md5` isn't secure (SHA-1 is prone to length extension attacks):

> Warning It is not recommended to use this function to secure
>   passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm. See the
>   Password Hashing FAQ for details and best practices.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php